# How to Create Different Colors for Tiles

Tags: python

I am relatively new to pygame, and I am trying to create a matching card game. I am currently stuck on how to replace the colors of the tiles. I currently have a list of colors for my tiles, but I do not know how I would implement each of these colors into my tiles. For example, tile 1 would be blue, tile 2 would be green, so on and so forth.

[Code for implementing board/tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEvyA.png)
[creation of board/random tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELM8Z.png)

I tried using a for loop to access each color, and then assign it to a variable, but I realized that this would not be the right way to go about it. I've also tried to create a for loop inside of a list, in my sqr_color, variable but this does not work either since I would have to access each color again inside the list. I also know that my self.assigned is working, since I can access specific colors.

Comment: Please edit the question, and replace the screen-shot of code with textual code.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a data structure to hold the various pieces of information about a tile.  It could be something as simple as a list:

```
tile1 = [ ( 255,   0,   0 ),  10, 10, 100, 100 ]
tile2 = [ (   0, 255,   0 ), 120, 10, 100, 100 ]
```

Where each tile is a python list of [ colour, x, y, width, height ].

Alternatively, you could create a class for each tile, and store the same thing:

```
class Tile():
    def __init__( self, colour, x, y, width=100, height=100 ):
        self.colour = colour
        self.x      = x
        self.y      = y 
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height
```

And then

```
tile1 = Tile( ( 255,  0,   0 ),  10, 10 )
tile2 = Tile( (   0, 255,  0 ), 120, 10 )
```

An easy way of processing all these tiles, is to put them into a list themselves:

```
all_tiles = [ tile1, tile2, ... ]
```

So building on this theme, to create a set of tiles where the colours come from a list:

```
all_tiles = []
color_index = 0
for i in range( 10 ):
    next_color = self.color[color_index]
    new_tile = Tile( next_color, 10+(i*110), 10 ) # create a tile
    all_tiles.append( new_tile )                  # add to tile-list

    if ( color_index >= len( self.color ) ):
        color_index = 0   # re-start from first colour again
    else:
        color_index += 1  # move to the next colour in list
```

So now you would have a set of 10 tiles in the list `all_tiles`, where the tile colours come from `self.colors`.  Note that if we run out of colours (the `len()` check), it starts from the first colour in the list again.